Calculate distance from destination at which to commence deceleration burn
For a vessel with insufficient fuel to burn for the entire duration of an interstellar journey, how do you calculate when to commence the deceleration burn?
Using this answer I can calculate the fuel fraction required for the acceleration and the deceleration phase. From the fuel fraction it is relatively simple to calculate the burn time required for the acceleration and deceleration phases
$t_b = \frac{m_f \times ff}{m_b}$
Where tb is burn time, mf is total fuel, ff is fuel fraction and mb is the mass of fuel burned per second.
What I can't figure out, however, is at what distance to commence the burn. Most examples I've found assume that you have exactly the right amount of fuel for the whole journey.
The following equation (from LibreTexts)
$S=V[t+(\frac{m_{0}}{b}-t)\ln(1-\frac{bt}{m_{0}})]$
gives the distance travelled from rest for a given burn - but I can't figure out how to adjust it for a starting velocity.

Maybe not a full answer - you could try using kinematics to determine how much distance you cover doing the burn and then applying that.

You don't really need to adjust for a starting velocity, because all motion is relative. You just have two frames of reference that you're going to accelerate between. You're thinking of the target frame as "zero" and the initial frame as "in motion", but you can just as easily reverse that: The ship is starting from rest and attempting to accelerate to a certain speed; how far does it travel in that time? And you already have the equation to do that.
Or to put that another way, decelerating from 100 arbitrary units to 0 is the same as accelerating from 0 to 100 in the other direction, you get the same distance either way. Once you have that answer, you know at what distance from the target you need to start your deceleration burn.

Thanks for the cold dash of reality! I started with this assumption and when my model yielded different results allowed myself to fall into the trap of trusting the model not the maths!
